# Saving file as same name but attaching date - referencing cell date

Tags: excel, vba, file-rename, chdir, fileopendialog

I'm able to run this code without any error, however is giving a slightly different objective.

It'll be added below the **Do Events** section according to the code in the link below.

[Loop through all excel file in given folder](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/23/loop-through-all-excel-files-in-a-given-folder)

Objective of code:

- Browse folder for workbook in folder with date referencing to a range "H2" of current workbook and saving them in the same folder as file browsed

Current Situation:

- Able to save file with date however it get saved in its earlier folder

> **E.g File exist in**
>
> C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\Test
>
> **New file with date will be saved in**
>
> C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop

**Codes**

```
Dim CellDate As String, fName As String

    fName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))



    CellDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H2")

    CellDate = Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD")


    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fName & "-" & CellDate, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

Appreciate the help (:

Comment: Why are you overriding `CellDate`?

Comment: Where is your code for finding the folder? You could be able to extract what you need from the return value of the folder path where found.

Comment: @QHarr I didn't put the code in, because is too long & is the same as the link listed above, no changes made to it [link](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/23/loop-through-all-excel-files-in-a-given-folder)

Comment: @FDavidov what do you mean by overriding?

Comment: You are first assigning to it the contents of cell `H2` and then override this with `Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD")`.

Comment: @FDavidov did `Format(Date,"YYYYMMDD")` because the next user for this workbook wouldn't understand if I customized the cell H2 in the format of YYYYMMDD, so I had H2 set as DD/MM/YYYY set in H2 for easier understanding

Comment: I can't see from this but you have presumably selected C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\Test from the folderdialog and thus this is the value of myPath so why not ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs myPath & fName & "-" & CellDate, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

Comment: Could you try PRINTING (or message) the values of `fName` and `CellDate`?

Comment: @FDavidov QHarr managed to solve it. Did tested `fName` & `CellDate`, which is filename & date value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs myPath & fName & "-" & CellDate, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

If your code for folder selection is as per the link then its value will be stored in myPath.

Assuming  "C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\Test" was the folder selected.

Note:

Associated code from link....

```
'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With
```